# Vertically long user interface

Tags: android, screen

I made a UI with many UI elements such as button and it takes a lot of space **vertically**.
The UI fits on my phone (it's 16:9 like many), but on phones with a different screen ratio, the buttons on the bottom are cut off of the screen.
I'm using a linear layout. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to create a UI that is like an image and displays at a fixed aspect ratio, start thinking about designing for resizing. To accomplish this, you need to make decisions about what in your layout must be fixed in size, and what can acceptably resize or scroll.

Importantly (and this is my own stylistic opinion), you should **avoid layouts that clutter the screen or fill it with detail**. Your layout sounds like an input form of some sort; one solution in your case might be to let the controls in the upper part of the menu scroll, while anchoring the buttons at the bottom of the screen, or to just place the whole layout in a scrolling view. But ask yourself: will this be user friendly? I suspect this solution will look dense and (on really small,  resistive displays like that of the LG Vortex) become hard to interact with.

Try to separate your UI into easy to comprehend little "nuggets", *omit unnecessary information*, and if you must, split the UI into different activities or fragments.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with all you sayd, I guess you will have the answer flag. what is the code for the "scrolling view" ?

Comment: I think an important question is, what's the most common aspect ratio of the android devices ? And how much common it is...

Comment: Suppose I can make the layout vertically shorter... well im not sure its an improvement......

Comment: @user3093325 Take a look at [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html); it should be what you're looking for. The answer to your aspect ratio question is that, while there are a few common ones, there is no ratio common enough that you should design around it and leave other ratios behind. The best apps have a consistent experience that avoids favoring a specific category of device (this is one reason that Android supports fragments for making UIs more comprehensive on larger screens).